# C++ Macro Arithmetric

Tags: c++, macros

I have to do with Macros (it's macros calling macros; so templates are out of the question).

Here's what I want:

```
foo(3, a, b1, c1) --> foo1(a, b1, c1);
foo(5, a, b1, c1, b2, c2) -> foo2(a, b1, c1, b2, c2);
foo(7, a, b1, c1, b2, c2, b3, c3) -> foo3(a, b1, c1, b2, c2, b3, c3);
```

So basically, what I want is to be able to execute the "function" n -> (n-1)/2 at macro expansion time. Is this possible?

[PS, if you dislike my questions; I support your right to downvote; my worst question so far is only -17, so maybe we can break that record; however, please let me know *why* my question is technically invalid.]

EDIT:

Foo takes a variable # of arguments, of the form:

```
foo(N, a1, b1, a2, b2, ... a_N, b_N) -> foo##N(a1, b1, a2, b2, ... a_N, b_N);
```

EDIT:

To all the closers. This is a very different question. The former is about "how do I count the # of arguments in a Macro." (to which there was a good response on the mailing list).

This question is a matter of: given I've counted the # of arguments, how do I dispatch on it?

Comment: Critically, the n -> (n-1)/2 mapping doesn't need to be captured by the macros — you only have a finite number of functions, right?

Comment: For what do you want such a contraption?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: correct. Only a finite # of functions.

Comment: Say for all odd n, between 1 & 63.

Comment: @anon: Don't underestimate yourself, the worst you've got is -26.

Comment: Looks like a very slightly reworded duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473262/c-var-arg-macro-not-template-closed.

Comment: @KennyTM: I didn't see that post. Can you provide a link?

Comment: @David - This question is slightly different, and answerable (or at least, got a good answer from Potatoswatter). The last one wasn't.

Comment: Yes, more parasitic behaviour. If you can't get people to do your work for them one way, try another. And I predict yet another, once this is closed.

Comment: You're on *my* bad side because 1) You ask *many* questions, provide few answers and get few votes for those you do offer; and yet you allude to sophisticated projects you're working on 2) you seem unable or unwilling to search 3) your questions tend to be imprecise, vague, without context, and unlikely to help anyone who comes later (this question is a prime example) and 4) you show no sign of being willing to work for yourself: rather that working from the dup of your previous post, you simply posted again and hoped we'd do your work. You can and should do better than that.

Comment: @Neil, dmckee: these are two different questions. The earlier was a matter of: "how do I count the # of arguments"; this problem has nothing to do with that -- the # of arguments is already known. The question is a matter of doing arithmetric computation on macro arguments at _macro expansion time_. Where is stuff like this documented? It's black magic to me.

Comment: @dmckee I respect your opinion. However, so long as I ask questions useful to me, and others find sufficiently interesting to spend time answering, what is there to lose?

Comment: I rest my case. The problem you describe imprecisely in your comment is not the problem you describe imprecisely in you question body and you clearly haven't taken the "there is no standard way to do vararg marcos" to heart, not spent any time trying to understand any particular vararg macro implementation nor said which one you are going to use. The answer to your question, BTW, is you *don't* do arithmetic at macro expansion time, you *only* do pure text rewriting on the code.

Comment: @dmckee: how are the two problems different? both my comment and my question talk about macro arithmetric and expansion time

Comment: @dmckee: this would be most useful: given that I want to do arithmetric at expansion time (the fact you don't want to use it doesn't mean others don't want to use it) -- how would you have liked the question to have been phrased / written?

Comment: @anon I think the thing that really gets up our noses is that when you ask a question there is no useful dialog between you and the answerer, and that your very few answers are actually comments (and not helpful ones at that). Here's my advice - spend a week without asking questions and in that week resolve to answer at least three. Oh, and change your nick.

Comment: @Chris Lutz:  Yes, you're right, although Potatoswatter's answer isn't what anon wanted, since anon wants the impossible.  My mistake.  I just voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but should work:

```
#define SUBSTFOO3( a, b1, c1 ) foo1(a, b1, c1)
#define SUBSTFOO5( a, b1, c1, b2, c2 ) foo2(a, b1, c1, b2, c2)
/* ad nauseam */

#define foo( N, ... ) SUBSTFOO ## N ( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

This might also work:

```
#define SUBSTFOO3 foo1 /* no arguments needed */
#define SUBSTFOO5 foo2 /* "( __VA_ARGS__)" already the correct substitution */

#define foo( N, ... ) SUBSTFOO ## N ( __VA_ARGS__ )
```

Comment: Might want to change to `#define foo3( a, b1, c1 ) (foo1)(a, b1, c1)` a) leave off the semicolon b) put parenthesis around the function name to prevent inadvertent macro expansion (in the case of `foo3`) or similar errors.

Comment: You're right about semicolons, but I don't think the parentheses would halt macro expansion. The way to be paranoid here would be to introduce your own `#define foo3 foo3`.

Comment: The `(foo1)(a, b, c)` is to prevent `foo(7, ...)` from simplifying to `foo7(a, b, c, d, e)` to `foo3(a, b, c, d, e)` to `error: macro "foo3" passed 7 arguments, but takes just 3` (which is what I get when I use GCC).

Comment: @Chris: ah, I see. I think the better solution is to avoid aliasing the names of the intermediate steps in the first place. Correcting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it reminds me of this trickery I saw in the GCC source.  Maybe you'll spot something applicable.

```
#if GCC_VERSION >= 3000 || __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
/* Use preprocessor trickery to map "build" to "buildN" where N is the
   expected number of arguments.  This is used for both efficiency (no
   varargs), and checking (verifying number of passed arguments).  */
#define build(code, ...) \
  _buildN1(build, _buildC1(__VA_ARGS__))(code, __VA_ARGS__)
#define _buildN1(BASE, X)   _buildN2(BASE, X)
#define _buildN2(BASE, X)   BASE##X
#define _buildC1(...)       _buildC2(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,0)
#define _buildC2(x,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,c,...) c
#endif
```